# Wrap text and elements in another element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a page which essentially looks like this:

```
<div id="foo">
    <a>One</a>, <a>Two</a>, <a>Three</a>, <a>Four</a>
</div>
```

<sub>*Extra attributes removed for the sake of brevity.*</sub>

There could be any number of links inside the div. What I want to do is to hide all the links after the *n* <sup>th</sup> one and add a "Show the rest" link. Basically, for that to happen (as far as I can see), I'd need to be able to transform it to look like this:

```
<div id="foo">
    <a>One</a>, <a>Two</a>, <a>More...</a>
    <span style="display: none"><a>Three</a>, <a>Four</a></span>
</div>
```

**How would you wrap the links in another element?**

Note that the obvious approach (`$('#foo a:gt(1)').wrapAll('<span>')`) will not work here, since there are text nodes (the commas) in between each link and these are not selected by that query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, adjust the index based on being `2n` since every text node counts as one now as well:

```
$(function() {
  var n = 4;
  $('#foo').contents()
    .filter(function(index){ 
         return index > n && ((this.nodeType==3)||(this.nodeName=="A"))})
    .wrapAll('<span style="background: red;">');
});
```

Comment: Why this approach? nickf simply wanted to hide all 'a' elements after an index.

Comment: @patrick - Look at the markup again...hiding all the `<a>` elements would leave lots of commas :)

Comment: Yes, you're right. It just hit me. Dang. I hate down-votes!  :o)

Answer (score 0):

For a start, maybe you should rewrite the element to be like this:

```
<div id="foo">
  <span><a>One</a></span>
  <span>, <a>Two</a></span>
  <span>, <a>Three</a></span>
  <span>, <a>Four</a></span>
</div>
```

Then you can easily show or hide any `foo` childrens that you want easily with `:gt` filter.